# iOS Progressive asset (or asset bundle) loading after app launch

Tags: ios, asynchronous, bundle, preload, assets

I'm looking to add more gradual/progressive asset loading to my iOS app, a bit like ZeptoLab do for Cut the Rope. I want to reduce the time the user spends on the static Default.png while the app loads, and hopefully arrive quicker to some Splash screen, where I can show a progress bar (I've spent some time developing in Flash, where 'preloaders' are the norm).

I gathered that I may have to use asset bundles for this. I want to still have all the files in Xcode, rather than being loaded from another location.

So I've seen examples on how to load an asset bundle -

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyBundle"  ofType:@"bundle"];
NSString *imageName = [myBundle pathForResource:@"someImage" ofType:@"png"];
```

But I wanted to find examples on how to:

- run this asynchronously, I guess by using another thread
- track how much of this bundle has loaded
- know how much this bundle contains, so I can calculate the percentage of the bundle that's been loaded.

I also wanted to know - does using asset bundles change how/when my files will be loaded by my iOS application?

Or is the correct approach to choose not to add files to the copy/build phases in my Xcode project's settings?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

thankfully file system access is threadsafe so loading a file on a thread is exactly what you need. i've heard of some grand central dispatch thing for ios... however pthreads work just fine as well. i do not have example code i can share, but i can say that this is not too hard if you already understand threading primitives to some degree (e.g. locks or even lockless techniques with atomic operations etc.)

you do not have to use separate bundles to achieve this - although there is no harm in using them either (for instance to keep separate those assets you want to load dynamically)